# how to change /1.php to index.php?id=1

Tags: php

```
if (file_exists($filename)) {
echo "<a class='next' href='$filename'><img  src='images/next.png'</a>";
} 
else {
echo "<img src='images/next-dis.png'/>";
}
```

---

well i am trying to do this I will have hudereds of pages like 1.php 2.php 3.php.... but i want them to look like this "index.php?id=1" instead of /1.php, /2.php and want to block users who try to access (for eg.) 2.php directly.. can anyone help?.. is there any simple way to do this?

Comment: you shoud do that in your `.htaccess`

Comment: i am searching for hours but i couldnt find. would you tell me what should i google to find it?

Answer (score 2):

The following rewrite rule in an Apache `.htaccess` file should do the trick.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule (\d+)\.php /index.php?id=$1
```

This basically matches any URL in the format `[0-9]+.php` and redirects it to `/index.php?id=###` where ### matches ###.php.

Comment: is there any reason why this wouldnt work? :(( when i click on the next it goes to 1.php but cant find the file. when i enter id=1 or anything the same page loads again:((

Comment: In this case, 1.php doesn't exist.  It is a virtual URL being rewritten by the server.  As long as `index.php` is at the root of your system, it should rewrite any URL like `/[0-9]+.php` to /index.php?id=###.  Where did you add the `.htaccess` file?  Also, make sure `AllowOverride` is set to `All` for your htdocs directory in `httpd.conf`.

Comment: I cant understand eighter... i put it in the htdocs where all my file including index.php and 1.php are stored. and allowoverride is set to all... now when i click next it opens /1.php but shows the content of the index.php ??  :(((

Comment: i think it is rewriting index.php?id=1 (which doesnt exist thats why it shows index.php content) to 1.php right now. i want the opposite way. thats why maybe??

Comment: The code given in the answer rewrites X.php to index.php?id=X so not sure it is that.

Comment: Make sure when you create your links you refer them to X.php not index.php?id=X.  The server takes care of mapping the fake URL to the actual URL through index.php

Comment: it is set that way.. maybe i should change something in index.php or x.php?? i just can't understand.. even when i go to 21312235234234534534534.php it shows the content of my index

Comment: and when i go to sdfdsfsd.php it shows my 404 page but when i go to jdhfk9.php it shows my index

Comment: Change to `RewriteRule ^(\d+)\.php /index.php?id=$1` to prevent it from matching jdhfk9.php.  But this is going to route everything to index.php so you can act appropriately based on the `id` parameter.

Answer (score 0):

Search for .htaccess rewrite rules. You will find examples on similar scenarios. See the practical solutions section in - http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.0/misc/rewriteguide.html

Answer (score -1):

Inside your index.php you could do this

```
include($_GET["id"]".php");
```

This will load whatever id is the get var, however anyone could change this variable and gain access to whatever they enter here.

Comment: Even with the warning.. I wouldn't post that without `<strike>` around it. People will read this and some think such an include is acceptable.

Comment: yeah, I had a second thought about posting it. But I wanted to show them that including another file dynamically is possible. The problem with htaccess is not all people have access to this file with services such as GoDaddy. If its a local test or you have full access to the server then this would definitely be the best way to go